# Has some change in Android 12 or API level 30+ broken notifications on some devices when using Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Xamarin android app that implements FCM notifications exactly as Microsoft describes in their Xamarin docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows

The app has worked flawlessly for many years. But since the release of Android 12, and the November 2021 requirement to target API level 30, we're not able to send notifications to a small number of users. Firebase says that the FCM token we are using (that was provided by the client) isn't registered or valid.

In at least one case, the problem just went away in a few days. But it persists for others. It doesn't affect all Android 12 users but the only people who have been impacted are Android 12 users. And so far it only seems to affect people who installed on a fresh Android 12 device. Users who upgraded from 11 to 12 aren't seeing the problem.

We are using the "old" Xamarin FCM libraries that Microsoft mentions in their documentation. The ones that still use OnTokenRefresh etc. Any attempts to use the newer libraries just results in seemingly unsolvable version conflicts between libraries.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: even after updating the app to use the very latest Xamarin and Firebase libraries, we are still getting invalid FCM tokens from the app.

Comment: It is rarely a Xamarin specific issue if Google API changes behavior. I highly suggest you get the newer FCM packages working. Perhaps describe which conflicts you get?

Comment: The conflicts I get are too absurd to go into. It's like DLL-hell of days of old. Fix one conflict only to create another one that can only be fixed by breaking what was just fixed. I was hoping to find someone who's successfully used the latest libraries to see exactly what combination of libraries they are using. And I'm ticked off that Microsoft's documentation references only some very old versions of the libraries.

Comment: I'm also kinda flummoxed by the fact that only some Android 12 devices are affected. I can't even reproduce the problem on my own devices or simulators.

Comment: We are using the latest FCM libraries no issues. So I am a little curious about what exactly you are seeing.

Comment: I think I've gotten past the version conflict issues. I just created a brand new project and started from the ground up and added only the latest versions of the libraries I needed. I now have a working app using the latest libraries. I'll test it shortly to see if using the latest version of everything fixes the problem we were having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem had nothing to do with compatibility issues in the FCM libraries. It was caused by changes in the way that the Android 12 WebView sends cookies. (We passed the FCM token as a cookie) Which oddly enough only impacted certain Android 12 devices but not all of them. The solution was to make sure we set the cookies with a full URL such as "https://example.org" and not site simply "example.org".